# Problem setting a property on an Asp.Net custom dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, events, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to set a property on a custom DropDownList:

```
<custom:ReferenceDropDownList ... ValidityDate="<%# Application.CreateDate %>" />
```

Even though I can see that Application.CreateDate has been set in the Page_Load method on the containing UserControl, the code-behind in the DDL never seems to pick it up.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // this.ValidityDate is always null
}
```

This is even the case with `ValidityDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>"`. The property of the DDL is declared like this:

```
[Category("Data")]
[DefaultValue(null)]
public DateTime? ValidityDate { get; set; }
```

Does anyone know what is the correct sequence I should be following here. I thought that a DDL would evaluate a cynamic property value like that without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `DataBind()` the page or control when using `<# ... >`.

Comment: It is being databound alright, it's just not picking up the properties that have been dynamically set, as opposed to those like DataTextField="ShortName", for instance